# Really simple PHP strlen/if question

Tags: php, if-statement, strlen

I am trying to take 2 strings, see what length they are, and if one is larger than the other, set it as `$phonenumber`, and the other as `$extension`.  See below:

```
if(strlen($temp_ext) > 4)
{
    $extension = $temp_cid;
    $phonenumber = $temp_ext;
}
else
{
    $extension = $temp_ext;
    $phonenumber = $temp_cid;
}
```

This doesn't look like it works, though.  I am still getting 10 digit numbers in extension, and 4 digit numbers in the `$phonenumber` variable.  What am I missing?

Comment: What does not work? Error? What value is in `$temp_ext`?

Comment: You need to use the `>=` operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
if(strlen($temp_ext) > strlen($temp_cid))
{
    $extension = $temp_cid;
    $phonenumber = $temp_ext;
}
else
{
    $extension = $temp_ext;
    $phonenumber = $temp_cid;
}
```

Hope this helps.